# Standard way to read parameters from header in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, best-practices, external-files

Suppose I have experimental data that I want to read from a file with parameters in the header. What is the standard way to read the parameters and make them available as tex macros. Consider the following example (the syntax of `mydata.dat` might be different if there is a way which fit's better with tex).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents} 


\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.dat}
paramA = 1 #Comment: Parameter A 
paramB = 20 #Parameter B
## Data begins ###
x y
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\calculated}{\paramA + \paramB}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymax=\paramB]
\addplot table {mydata.dat} node[above]{\paramB}; %should automatically skip the header lines without saying of how much lines to skip
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy solution is to use LaTeX commands in the file and use `\input`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,filecontents,pgfplotstable} 

\begin{filecontents}{mydata.tex}
\def\paramA{1} %Comment: Parameter A 
\def\paramB{20} %Parameter B
\pgfplotstableread{
x y
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
}\mydata
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\input{mydata}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\calculated}{\paramA + \paramB}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymax=\paramB]
\addplot table {\mydata} node[above]{\paramB}; %should automatically skip the header lines without saying of how much lines to skip
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```